# scrapy 503 error callback

Tags: python, scrapy

When I use scrapy crawl pages with FormRequest I encountered http 503 error. What I wanna ask is how could I call a function when I encounter http 503 error. 
For example, when it raise http 503 error the scrapy would retry the page and after 3 times it would finally close the spider. If it's http 404 error or 500 error, I could use errback parameter of FormRequest so I can handle the exception. But when http 503 error raised it doesn't work. Could you tell me the solve of this problem?

Comment: I've edited the question to make it more clear